# Rename file in same folder using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to rename a file in same folder how can i achieve this?

for now i am using

```
File.Move(Server.MapPath(p.FilePath), Server.MapPath("~/Programs/test/Outputs/" + UserID + "/") + ID +".pdf");
```

Comment: It seems correct to me. Be careful with the UserId and Id variables. Maybe you need to add .toString()

Comment: is there a problem with that code? there is no `rename` as far as I'm aware.

Comment: yes i know there is no rename. But i want to rename file in same folder i mean i don't to write server.mappath over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is a solution, you can try `Path.GetDirectoryName`

```
 File.Move(Server.MapPath(p.FilePath), Server.MapPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Server.MapPath(p.FilePath)))+"\\" "filename");
```

Comment: Good answer but take care of rights on IIS 7 in production environnement